# JS How to check if callback is exist?

Tags: javascript, callback, call

I have array of registered callbacks

```
this.events[eventName].push({callback: callback});
```

The problem is that, than after user actions in array can be added the same calback, which already exists.

How to check that callback is exist?

What will be happening, if two same callbacks will be registered from two several places of code? It is logical that they should be executed. The question is, how not to re-register a callback call from the same place.

Comment: What do you mean by "*from the same place*"? A function does not have any notion of the execution context it was called from. It knows about its own context and has closures to variables of outer contexts, but you can't reference the contexts in any way, so can't pass a reference either. I think you need to post a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to provide more detail.

Answer (score 3):

A data structure that is suitable for this, is the ES6 `Map`. If you use that instead of an array, it will automatically only store uniques:

```
this.events = new Map(); // one time initialisation instead of `this.events = []`;
// ...
this.events[eventName].set(callback, {callback: callback});
```

And execute the callbacks for an event as follows:

```
this.events[eventName].forEach(({callback}) => callback());
```

If the callback is the only thing you store, then you could use a `Set` instead:

```
this.events = new Set();
// ...
this.events[eventName].add(callback);
```

And execute the callbacks for an event as follows:

```
this.events[eventName].forEach(callback => callback());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if the callback already exists:

```
if (!this.events[eventName].some(function(el) {
    return el.callback == callback;
}) {
    this.events[eventName].push({callback: callback});
}
```

Comment: What will be happening, if two same callbacks will be registered from two several places of code? It is logical that they should be executed. Your solution will not be register the second callback. The question is, how not to re-register a callback call from the same place.

Comment: There's no way to tell where the callback was registered from. Why should it make a difference? Either you want to allow duplicate callbacks or you don't.

Comment: I don't know that compares in ```el.callback == callback```, if this is function pointers, yes, it should well work.

Comment: Yes, it compares function pointers. The caller needs to be passing the *same* function each time -- anonymous functions might not match because the closure environment differs.

Comment: Anonymous functions won't match if they are different functions: `function(){} !== function(){}`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a simple loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.events[eventName].length; i++)
  if (this.events[eventName].callback === callback)
    return;    // already exists, so return without pushing

this.events[eventName].push({callback: callback});
```

Comment: What will be happening, if two same callbacks will be registered from two several places of code? It is logical that they should be executed. Your solution will not be register the second callback. The question is, how not to re-register a callback call from the same place.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My code checks whether a *specific* function has already been added to the array. If you're registering callbacks from different parts of your code they would presumably not be the same function, so both would register. If you are using anonymous functions they will *not* be considered the same as each other even from the same part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` function to check if callback exists

```js
class Observer {
  constructor(){
    this.events = {};
  }
  
  on(name, callback){
    if(typeof name !== 'string' || typeof callback !== 'function') return this;
    let ary = this.events[name] || (this.events[name] = []);
    if(ary.some(obj => obj.callback === callback)) return this;
    ary.push({callback});
    return this;
  }
}

let observer = new Observer();
function testHandler(){}
observer.on('test', testHandler)
  .on('test', testHandler);
  
console.log(observer.events);
```